# g++-4.3 not in repos anymore, how to install it?

Tags: 11.04, g++

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and need g++-4.3 for a project. What is the best way to install it, since it is not present in the repositories anymore.

Do I have to build it from source or is there a better way? Using an older package of one older ubuntu release brings me in a dependency hell...

Comment: Thanks, but thats not helping since when I install the .deb with `dpkg -i` there are missing dependencies, and when I try to manually fix those dependencies I have the dependency hell I described above.

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks I usually create a [Virtual Machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) with the proper tools and bridged networking. Both [Lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gcc-4.3) and [Maverick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gcc-4.3) have gcc-4.3 available. If you had a CD image of these versions available, boot into it and setup a SSH server. This SSH server is optional, you could use the Terminal inside the VM as well, but you cannot interact with the clipboard of the host system without installing [Guest Additions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/virtualbox-guest-additions).

(to save resources, I would use [Debian Squeeze](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/#netinst-stable) which has [gcc-4.3](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gcc-4.3) as well. Whether this is possible depends on the dependencies of your package)

Answer (score 0):

since installing deb brings you into depency hell, maybe chrooting older ubuntu ( which have g++ 4.3) could help

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

or, building from source